# Facebook Debugger Error: type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided

Tags: debugging

I'm a bit at my wits end here.

I have these webpages:

www.rachelgrantcoaching.com/group-program-men

and

www.rachelgrantcoaching.com/group-program

and

www.rachelgrantcoaching.com/brokentobeyond

The code is all the same. I have the same meta tags with some changes for site URL and image.

In the debugger, /brokentobeyond used to work just fine, so I copied that code to add to the other two pages.

Now all of them return this error:

Object at URL 'http://rachelgrantcoaching.com/group-program/' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.

I have an og:title on all of these pages.

I don't know what "of type 'string'" means...

Even stranger -- when I enter these URLs in Facebook as if to post, all but /group-program-men show up as I'd like them to.

What's going on here?

How do I get FB to recognize that the og:title is there so that the image and text will display correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook isn't following all your redirects:

> http://www.rachelgrantcoaching.com/brokentobeyond

Permanently redirects to (this is where Facebook stops following the redirects):

> http://rachelgrantcoaching.com/brokentobeyond

Which permanently redirects to

> http://rachelgrantcoaching.com/brokentobeyond/

This last one has the content with meta tags, this is what you want Facebook to read.

However, Facebook stops on the middle one which actually looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://rachelgrantcoaching.com/brokentobeyond/">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

Instead make http://www.rachelgrantcoaching.com/brokentobeyond redirect to http://rachelgrantcoaching.com/brokentobeyond/ and it should pick up the page with all the meta tags.

I'm a bit surprised Facebook isn't following all the redirects tbh.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm not sure how to follow your next steps though. I created the page in Leadpages, and then publish via HTML on my server. I can edit code in Coda.  On my server, I have the folder /brokentobeyond with the index.php file. I'm not even sure where this brokentobeyond/ page is coming from.  I tried adding this code in my index file: <META http-equiv="refresh" content="0: URL=http://rachelgrantcoaching.com/brokentobeyond/"> -- but when I scrape for new information, the errors are gone, but all the preview image shows is this URL.

Comment: Well -- I went back to scratch, starting with leadpages, and updated all three pages and it now seems to bee working!!